# Differentiate between touch count SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, touch

Below, I have implemented test to understand touch count behaviour of touchable sprite (`sprite.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`)

When I check in:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        print("touched sprite = name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite'", "tapCount=", touch.tapCount, NSDate())
    }
}
```

And here are some of my touch result:

When I touch frequently it just gives keeps increasing touch count:

> touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:11:50 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 2 2016-09-12 13:11:51 +0000
>   performDoubleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 3 2016-09-12 13:11:51 +0000
>   performTrippleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 4 2016-09-12 13:11:51 +0000
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 5 2016-09-12 13:11:51 +0000
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 6 2016-09-12 13:11:52 +0000
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 7 2016-09-12 13:11:52 +0000

---

Then once I paused for a while it starts counting from 1 again check the breaks.

> touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:11:53 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions

---

> touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:12:16 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 2 2016-09-12 13:12:17 +0000
>   performDoubleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 3 2016-09-12 13:12:17 +0000
>   performTrippleTapActions

---

> touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:12:18 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:12:20 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions

---

> touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 1 2016-09-12 13:12:21 +0000
>   performSingleTapActions
>   touched sprite =  name:'WalkBoyTouchSprite' tapCount= 2 2016-09-12 13:12:21 +0000
>   performDoubleTapActions

I need to implement one action Once It is tapped 1 time, another in case of 2 taps (as you an see in test logs). But the problem is it calls in sequence. That means if I apply Action1, Action2 and Action3 on respective touch count all 3 will be activated.

What can be smart way to differentiate between single and multiple touch? Like if I can get exact required pause time (after which it start counting from 1), or something else that is even better.

Comment: just use  the tap count in a switch statement

Comment: Still it will be calling case 1 then 2 then 3.

Comment: oh, I get you,  if you do a double tap, you want the first one to be ignored

Comment: Yes, that's right, same in case of all the tap. Each tap count need to be act as different event. Not touch even with different count.

Comment: then tap count is not what you want, you could the switch to save the action required in a block, then attach a tap gesture to the view,  when the gesture command executes, fire the block corresponding to the touch

Comment: It's for `SKSpriteNode`, can we add gesture recogniser to `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123167/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-rptwsthi).

Comment: no, has to be on the SKView

Comment: that is why you need to save the action in a block,  so you know which sprite to fire the action,  you just use the skview and tap gesture to determine the amount of taps,  you wouldn't be able to determine what sprite got tapped until you evaluate the touch position (but why waste time searching)

Answer (score 1):

`UITouch` contains `tapCount` as well as `timestamp`. In order to do what you want, you are going to need to define a clear set of rules for tapping. This defines the number of taps you are supporting as well as acceptable time durations and cutoffs for taps. Some of this will require playing the game to tune what time values work best.

Based on your rules, you can make a state machine to govern what gets game event triggered (e.g. this is a 1 tap event). The key part is to be able to "flush" any incoming noise from additional touches once you've determined an event has occured.

Let's start with a 1 touch event. For this, you need to define some dt (delta time) between taps which constitute that is that dt is surpassed without another tap, it will be deemed only 1 tap. So even though you are getting more touch events based on taps, you are going to ignore them once the dt threshold has been passed.

In order to do this, you'll need to have additional logic running at regular intervals (usually frame rate) which is tracking past input (ie. you are tracking history of input). For example, the logic could be something like:

```
if  (now - lastGoodTap.timestamp) > THRESHOLD) {
    // Do my one tap goodness
}
```

You would really want this run in 2 places: your periodic input logic which tracks input history and your input logic which processes `touchesEnded` events (to check to see if `lastGoodTap` and the current timestamp has surpassed the threshold in order to categorize if it is 1 tap or now 2). In the `touchesEnded` if you receive the next `tapCount` (ie. `tapCount == 2`) AND the threshold has not been reached, you now classify this event as a 2 tap scenario.

Doing 2 and 3 taps are extensions of the 1 tap case. For games which have special moves or do multi-tap, you actually need to track input state. I usually support special moves as well as secret inputs for things like debug. Typically I create another class to track this history state. It has a reference to the `UITouch` but copies over the `timestamp` as well as keeps track of what it thinks it's current tap count is.

Keep in mind that you will use the `UITouch` instance as a key/reference to the input stream, since that will let you know you are looking at the same touch. This is important if you are multi-touch.

Additionally, you will want to handle the case of non-stop multi-tap to make sure you do the right things (for example, you could always just discard a UITouch with tapCount > 3).

An easy way to model this is with an empty project and using `NSLog` to help watch events and state go through live.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution or say Hack. I give it some time to user to tap. This time start with user's first tap and ends after **X** second. All the taps registered during this time period will be the count of taps that I will entertain.

Something like this:

```
var touchCount = 0
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    //to implement multiple touch

    if self.touchCount == 0 {
        self.delay(1.0, closure: {
            //self.delegate?.touched(self, touches: touches, with : event)
            self.touchingFinished()
        })
    }

    //increment touch count
    self.touchCount += 1
}

func touchingFinished() {
    print("tapping finished, count = ", touchCount)
    switch self.touchCount {
    case 1://do one thing
    case 2://do other thing
    default://do somethign
        break;
    }
    //touch task done now re initialize touchCount
    self.touchCount = 0
}
```

Don't forget to disable `userInteraction` once you started your task sequence.